# Rails model has_many :items twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, database-design, model

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :videos
end
```

video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I want users to be able to add videos to their 'collection' that don't `belongs_to` them (were not uploaded by  them).

I guess I will need a many to many relationship so I have considered a `has_many` through a 'collection' join model.  I don't understand how I would then differentiate between uploaded and collected videos.

I have also considered two new models a 'collection' model that `belongs_to :user` and `has_many :videos` through a 'collected_videos' join model.

Is there a better way to go around implementing this? Sorry if my question is not clear, new to StackOverflow and development in general. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, I think you can set things up something like this to achieve what you want:

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end

class Video
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
end
```

Take a closer look at the documentation for `has_and_belongs_to_many`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: @tet5uo did the above answer solve your issue? Noticed this answer hadn't been marked accepted yet :)